Higher cohomology groups of $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $1$-forms with values in $q$-forms
Consider the category of simplicial presheaves on the site of cartesian spaces (i.e., objects are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and morphisms are smooth maps. The coverage is given by good open covers of cartesian spaces).
Let $G$ be a Lie group and let $\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g})$ be the presheaf of 1-forms with values in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. I am interested in the cohomology groups $H^i(\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g});\Omega^q)$ for $i>0$.
More precisely, let $\Omega^q[i]$ denote the simplicial presheaf obtained by applying the Dold–Kan functor (objectwise) to the sheaf of chain complexes with $\Omega^q$ concentrated in degree $i$ and $0$'s in all other degrees. Define
$$H^i(\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g});\Omega^q):=\pi_0\mathbb{R}{\operatorname{Map}}(\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g}),\Omega^q[i])$$
where $\mathbb{R}{\operatorname{Map}}$ denotes the derived mapping space in, say, the local projective model structure. Taking $i=0$, the group $H^0(\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g}),\Omega^q) $ was computed by Freed and Hopkins and is given by the degree $q$ component of the Weil algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.
Have the groups $H^i(\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g}),\Omega^q)$ been computed for $i>0$?
I suspect these groups vanish, but the calculation is complicated by the fact that cofibrant resolutions of $\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g})$ are quite large. Computing the Čech cohomology is involved and one cannot appeal to the usual partitions of unity argument, as in the case of smooth manifolds.
If $X$ is a simplicial manifold, the usual argument using partitions of unity can be adapted to work in the more general setting in order to show that $H^i(X;\Omega^q)=0$ for $i>0$. So in this case, the higher cohomology groups do vanish. Hence, the class of smooth stacks that are acyclic for $\Omega^q$ contains all simplicial manifolds. If $X$ is homotopy invariant, then using the cohesive adjunction between simplicial presheaves and spaces, one can show that the cohomology vanishes in all degrees (for $q>0$). This leads me to a second question.
Is there an example of a simplicial presheaf $X$ such that: 1. $X$ is not homotopy invariant; 2. $X$ is not weakly equivalent to a simplicial manifold; 3. $H^i(X;\Omega^q)=0$ for $i>0$?

@PeterHaine This does not compute what I want. The way Freed and Hopkins define the complex $\Omega^*(\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g}))$ is (in my notation) $H^0(\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g}),\Omega^q)$ in degree $q$, with differential induced by the de Rham differential $d:H^0(\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g}),\Omega^q))\to H^0(\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g}),\Omega^{q+1}))$. I am asking about the higher cohomology groups $H^i(\Omega^1(-;\mathfrak{g});\Omega^q)$ for $i>0$.

Sorry, misread your question!
